# Fittext does not apply after changing the font-family

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, fittextjs

Im using the plugin [fittextjs](http://fittextjs.com/) to automatically resize my fonts to make them fit to the current div width's. For example i use it here in the `<span>`:

```
<ion-view class="menu-content" view-title="Polaroid">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="polaroid">
            <div class="polaroid-img">
                <img ng-src="{{polaroid.cropped}}" />
            </div>
            <div class="polaroid-title">
                <span data-fittext style="font-family: {{polaroid.style}}">{{polaroid.title}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The keyword here is `data-fittext`. When i open the html page the resizing of the font size gets applied without problems. Also when im resizing the changing of the font size works very good.

Now i navigate forward to another page where i can change the font style. The changing of the font style works perfectly. When i navigate back the font style is applied..

BUT

The fittext does not apply. The text size gets very small (i guess 10px). I have to resize my page so that fittext applies the font-size again.

Why does fittext does not apply the font-size after changing the font-family?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't follow exactly what you are saying about how the font gets changed but there is no event for JS to detect changing for the font. FitText only listens to resize and orientationchange events, it's a pretty simple function.

I would just call fittext again, after the font has changed.

UPDATE: Just looked at your code again, your font family directive might be overwriting the style attribute when polaroid.style changes. This would remove the fittext styles. Maybe use a class to indicate the font-family rather than inline styles

Comment: i cant do that. its a font chooser. I have to set the style like that.

Comment: move your `style="font-family: {{polaroid.style}}"` attribute to the parent div then. Then they won't conflict.

Comment: I have no idea why.. but that fixed the problem.

Comment: Because fittext and your style attr directive were both trying to write to the same style attr, so they overwrote each other